# Игнорирование условия в While С++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++, visual-studio-2013

Задание такое: заполнить матрицу Nного порядка и посчитать

1) Сумму элементов в тех строках, которые не содержат отрицательных элементов

2) минимум среди сумм элементов диагонале, параллельных главной диагонали матрицы.
Если первое работает на ура, то со вторым возникли такие затруднения:

При подсчёте сумм диагоналей параллельных главной, в цикле где это происходит есть вылет за массив у переменных x и y хотя в while чётко прописано, что если ((x < N - 1) ИЛИ (y < N - 1)) то считать сумму диагонали, однако это условие игнорируется и x выходит дальше за массив. Наблюдается в g++ и visual-c
Вопрос, почему игнорируются условия в while?

```
// PR5_din_arrays.cpp: определяет точку входа для консольного приложения.
//
/*Дана целочисленная квадратная матрица. Определить:
1) Сумму элементов в тех строках, которые не содержат отрицательных элементов
2) минимум среди сумм элементов диагонале, параллельных главной диагонали матрицы.
*/

// PR5_din_arrays.cpp: определяет точку входа для консольного приложения.
//
/*Дана целочисленная квадратная матрица. Определить:
1) Сумму элементов в тех строках, которые не содержат отрицательных элементов
2) минимум среди сумм элементов диагонале, параллельных главной диагонали матрицы.
*/

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    int N = 2;
    cout << "input the size of matrix" << endl;
    cin >> N;
    while (N < 2)
    {
        cout << "incorrect value!" << endl;
        cout << "input the size of matrix" << endl;
        cin >> N;
    }
    /* в куске выше я объявляю N которая отвечает за порядок матрицы. После её ввода идёт защита от дурака, которая не пускает дальше, если введённое значение меньше 2.
    В случае если будет матрица первого порядка, то задача потеряет смысл*/
    int **matrix = new int*[N];
    for (int count = 0; count < N; count++)
    {
        matrix[count] = new int[N];
    }
    /*выше объявляю саму матрицу*/
    int *sum = new int[N]; // в этот массив пишутся суммы строк. Должен быть динамическим ибо мы не знаем какого порядка будет матрица
    int ds = (N - 1) * 2; // это формула вычисления количества диагоналей параллельных главной. Чтобы включить сюда главную диагональ, нужно к полученному результату прибавить единицу
    int *diasum = new int[ds+1]; // массив в который будут попадать суммы диагоналей
    srand(time(NULL));
    cout << "Original array:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        sum[i] = 0; // обнуление массива сумм! ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО! иначе на выходе получим очень интересные и многозначные данные которые называются мусором
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = rand() % 101 - 50;
            cout << setw(6) << left << matrix[i][j]; // тут setw(6) устанавливает расстояние между символами потока вывода, left сдвигает всё влево. ЧТОБЫ РАБОТАЛО НУЖЕН <iomanip>
        }
        cout << endl;

    }
    cout << "sdelan vyvod - perehod k vychisleniyu summy stroki" << endl;
    /*в куске выше я рандомил матрицу от -50 до 50(100 чисел и сдвиг по числовой линии влево на 50 101 потому что 0 тоже число*/
    //вычисления
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            if (matrix[i][j] < 0)
            {
                sum[i] = 0;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                sum[i] = sum[i] + matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
    }cout << "vycheslena stroka - perehod k onuleniyu DIASUM" << endl;/*выше я иду по строке и проверяю число на отрицательность. Если отрицательное - обнуляю сумму и выхожу из цикла, таким образом перехожу на след. строку
     Если же всё окей, то просто прибавляю число в sum[i]. */
    /*
    _____________________________________________________________________

    Ниже пойдёт отработка диагоналей

    _____________________________________________________________________
    */
    for (int i = 0; i < ds; i++)
    {
        diasum[i] = 0;
        cout << diasum[i] << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "DIASUM obnulena - perehod k vychisleniyu summy diagonali - 1 prohod" << endl;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int iter = 0; // Сюда ловим место на котором мы остановилис в цикле ниже, чтобы с него затем продолжить. 

    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
    {
        x = i;
        y = 0;
        cout << x << "   " << y << "   " << matrix[y][x] << endl;
        while ((x < N - 1) || (y < N - 1))
        {
            diasum[i - 1] = diasum[i - 1] + matrix[y][x]; // p.s вот здесь и происходят интересные вещи. при N = 4 x не должен быть больше 3, но он таки почему-то больше, хотя в цикле while написано о том, что если x или y больше 3 то вывалиться и посчитать следующую диагональ(или идти дальше если цикл for закончился
            x++;
            y++;
            iter = i - 1;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= iter; i++) //вывод сумм чисел, пока что в лобешник все подряд.
    {
        cout << "      " << diasum[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "DIASUM obnulena - perehod k vychisleniyu summy diagonali - 2 prohod" << endl;

    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
    {
        y = i;
        x = 0;
        cout << x << "   " << y << "   " << matrix[y][x] << endl;
        while ((y < N - 1) || (x < N - 1))
        {
            diasum[iter + i] = diasum[iter + i] + matrix[y][x]; // а здесь после нескольких шагов можно поймать ACCESS_VIOLATION
            x++;
            y++;
        }
    }
// конец блока отработки диагоналей.
    for (int i = 0; i < ds; i++) //вывод сумм чисел, пока что в лобешник все подряд.
    {
        cout << "      " << diasum[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "perehod k vyvodu" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) //вывод сумм чисел, пока что в лобешник все подряд.
    {
        cout <<"      " <<sum[i];
    }
        cout << endl;
        //cout << ds;
        system("pause"); // задерживаем консоль до ввода клавиши
    return 0;
}
```

**Примечания** 
1. я знаю о том, что в коде может быть немного странная работа с дин.массивом diasum
2. код комментировался до написания куска отработки диагоналей и был прокомментирован для одногруппников.

Comment: Есть идея костылизировать циклы while которые работают с диагоналями: сделать простые условия, но внутрь подставить второе условие которое при false будет вышибать нас из цикла.. Если первое будет равно истине, то второе будет нас выбрасывать и заставлять идти дальше

Comment: Что значит "игнорирование"? Ваш код делает ровно то, что вы там написали, с помощью отладки вы можете увидеть почему происходит не то, что вы желаете видеть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Должно быть while ((x < N - 1) && (y < N - 1)). Так как Вы проверяете И тот (x) И тот (y) диапазон, а не хотя бы один.

Answer (score 1):

Рассмотрим Ваш цикл while:

```
x = i;
y = 0;
while ((x < N - 1) || (y < N - 1)) {
    //...
    x++;
    y++;
}
```

Перед циклом **`x`** у нас всегда больше нуля.
**`y`** же всегда будет равно нулю.
Условие цикла гласит 
продолжать пока 
x меньше N - 1
**ИЛИ**
y меньше N - 1

На каждой итерации **x** и **y** увеличиваются на 1.

Всё это значит, что при i == 2 мы уже получим выход за пределы массива. Предлагаю для простоты рассмотреть примерчик. 
Пусть N == 3, i == 1.
Тогда x == 1, y == 0.
Получаем условие: (1 < 2) || (0 < 2) оно дает true, поэтому продолжаем цикл.
В цикле x и y увеличиваются.
Дальше по итерациям:
(2 < 2) || (1 < 2) == true
(3 < 2) || (2 < 2) == false
Вышли из while и начинается новая итерация for:
x == 2, y == 0
(2 < 2) || (0 < 2) == true
(3 < 2) || (1 < 2) == true
Как видим, x уже равен трем, а условие дает true,
поэтому мы успешно заходим в цикл и выходим за пределы выделенной памяти.

Comment: Найдено. Ошибка действительно была в неверном логическом операторе. Нужно было писать И. Более того, было замечено игнорирование концевых элементов матрицы A(0.N) и A(M.0)